# How to bundle a promise from a then and catch block

Tags: javascript, promise

I am trying to chain data from an API request together and would like to gather promises from two of the blocks into a third `then`.

The pattern is as follows:

```
sql.connect(config.properties).then(pool => {
  return pool.request()
    .execute('stored_proc')
    .then(response => { res.send(response) })
    .catch(err => { res.send(err) })
    .then((response, err) => { someFunction(response, err) }) // bundle here
    .finally(() => sql.close())
})
```

How can I pass `response` and `err` into the second `then` block to pass into a function?

Comment: am not sure why `err` is in your `then`. to return the response, do something like: `.then((response, err) => { someFunction(response, err); return response; }).then(response => { DoSomething(response); }`

Comment: Can you use `async / await`, if you not using a very old version of node, then the answer here would be yes.   One advantage of `async/await` here is that you have the benefits of closures, if not you will have to pass everything down the promise chain.

Comment: @Santi  In theory the execute could succeed, but the res.send could fail, so you could have a response and error.

Comment: @Keith Understood, thank you.

Comment: With `someFunction` id like to pass either `response` or `err` to a log...

Comment: I'm not sure if `res.send` is async, but my guess would be yes. I can't find its full definition in the `Express` docs.

Comment: @Keith What would the `async/await` pattern look like?

Comment: @Matthew  I'll knock up a quick snippet..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend calling the `someFunction` in the two locations where those values are actually available:

```
return pool.request()
.execute('stored_proc')
.then(response => {
  res.send(response);
  someFunction(response, null);
})
.catch(err => {
  res.send(err);
  someFunction(null, err);
})
.finally(() => sql.close())
```

However, given the [difference between `.then(…, …)` and `.then(…).catch(…)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572) I would in fact recommend

```
return pool.request()
.execute('stored_proc')
.then(response => {
  res.send(response);
  someFunction(response, null);
}, err => {
  res.send(err);
  someFunction(null, err);
})
.finally(() => sql.close())
```

Now if you really want to pass the values into a following `then` callback, you can simply `return` them. Use an array to transport two values:

```
return pool.request()
.execute('stored_proc')
.then(response => {
  res.send(response);
  return [response, null];
}, err => {
  res.send(err);
  return [null, err];
})
.then(([response, err]) => {
  someFunction(response, err);
})
.finally(() => sql.close())
```

Comment: Your first example is what I had originally, but am on a quest to clean up the code a bit...

Comment: The second example looks promising, but I need to read up on the nuances between `then(..., ...)` and `then(...).catch(...)`.

Comment: The third is very much in the spirit of this question, but is syntactically somewhat heavy.

Comment: @Matthew The third example is exactly what you are needing !

Answer (score 0):

Using `async/await`, that is now included with Node.js.

You could do something like ->

```
sql.connect(config.properties).then(async pool => {
  try {
    let response = null; //let's set to null, in case it doesn't even get that far
    try {
      response = await pool.request().execute('stored_proc');
      res.send(response);
      someFunction(response, null);
    } catch (err) {
      res.send(err);
      someFunction(response, err);
    }
  } finally {
    sql.close();
  }
})
```

The advantage here is that we can keep a closure on the response, I've set it to null also, because in theory it might not even get as far as getting a response.

What make `async/await` do nice, it that you can go back to thinking in a `sync` way, but the code still runs `async`, so all normal try / catch / finally work as you would expect, for loops work as you would imagine etc.  Just be careful of `Array.forEach`, and thing's that take callbacks, as that might not work the way you expect.

Comment: OP also wants to call `someFunction` when there was no error?

Comment: I am getting an `await is only valid in async function` error with this example.

Comment: Ah, I see now!!

Comment: Thank you for your help!! :)